# Как посмотреть IL код прямо в Visual Studio? C#

Tags: c#

Видел как-то на скриншоте, у программиста было открыто окно с IL кодом прямо в visual studio, как он это сделал возможности спросить не было. Подскажите?

Использую Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Поставил плюстк за вопрос, мне тоже интересно. Я могу подсказать Вам то решение, котрым пользуюсь сам: LinqPad - там в полной (не той, котрая бесплатно на сайте раздаётся) версии есть декомпилятор. Выглядит изумительно: https://junecat.ru/Storage/Others/linqpad7.png

Comment: @S.H. благодарю, будет полезно

Comment: вы так же можете посмотреть IL/Asm/Decompile на sharplab.io

Comment: Он сделал это ReSharper-ом

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Меня этот вопрос тоже заинтересовал, и я постарался поискать информацию. Нашел не сразу.

Благодаря замечанию vitidev к моему ответу - я знаю, что это, скорее всего, [решарпер](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

В нём эта функция включается через ReSharper -> Windows -> IL Viewer в меню решарпера.

На картинках 7 и 8 показано, как включить, и результат. Конечно, очень красивый - как ивсё у JetBrains.

В VS есть прекрасный "обычный дебаггер" - потому, что это общий дебаггер для всех типов проектов.

Его можно вызвать `Debug > Windows > Dissasembly` (Ctrl + Alt + D). Вызывается только в режиме отладки.

Он показывает "дизассемблнутый" машинный код, что, конечно же, не является MSIL-ом. Заметим, что есть особенность: MSIL при компиляции в машинный код обрабатыветя еще и JIT'ом, так что однозначного сооветствия между командой MSIL и группой команд ассемблера может не быть.

Как примерно выглядит - показано на картинке 1 в конце ответа.

Следующее, что приходит в голову - это **ILDASM**. Вызывается как отдельная программа, дизассемблирует сборки (*.dll и *.exe, по простому говоря), написанные на NET, в MSIL. Поскольку эта штука приходит вместе со студией, (или, возможно, вмесие с NET core SDK?) - то поддерживает все версии NET, от старенького NET Framework и до NET Core.

Не позволяет производить отладку, только показывает MSIL-код.

Показан на картинке 2.

Есть прекрасный - судя по отзывам - инструмент, который называется **NET Reflector** (производства Redgate). Интегрируется с VS. Вызывается прямо из VS. Платный. Но, судя по видео на их сайте, он осуществляет скорее "дизасеемблирование в исходный код" каких то чужих бинарников и отладку на уровне исходного кода. По моему, окна с MSIL там нет. Еслия ошибаюсь - может, кто то, кто с Reflector'ом работал - меня поправит?

Видео с демонстрацией работы - на [этой](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) их странице.

Мне очень понравился инструмент, котрый я уже упомянул в комментарии к вопросу - написанный Джозефом Албахари (да-да, тем самым, который написал "C#. Справочник. Полное описание языка") **LinqPad**. Помимо хороших возможностей по отладке LINQ и SQL запросов, там есть также (в профессиональной версии) трансляция в IL - код.

Видео про использование [на ютьюбе](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBFtu07hFkw)

Картинка 3.

И последнее, что мне попалось -наверное, самое близкое к "отладке IL кода".
Это проект венгерского программиста Zsolt Petrény под названием **Dotnet IL Editor** (DILE).

Эта штука позволяет отлаживать  .NET 1.0/1.1/2.0/3.0/3.5/4.0 - сборки.

Я эту штуку взял из [гитхаба](https://github.com/alexhiggins732/DILE-MSIL-DEBUGGER) и собрал (пришлось подправить буквально пару ссылок на DLL-ки в с++ - сной части проекта).

Она позволяет загружать и запускать сборки - с теми ограничениями на версию фремворка, которые я только что написал.

При этом есть особенность, которая отражена на картинке 4 в конце ответа - нужно после загрузки сборки в DILE назначить startup assembly.

Потом можно поставить breakpoint и по шагам отлаживать IL - код.

Процесс отладки простого кода (чуть ниже) показан на картинке 5.

Чего не хватает: я не нашел, как посмотреть память (дамп памяти).
Самое близкое к этому - просмотр объектов, показанный на картинке 6.

Вообще, штука мощная, учитывая, что это отладчик с исходными кодами - то есть, теоратически, его можно попробовать улучшать под свои нужды.

Если у кого то есть еще идеи - буду рад, если Вы ими поделитесь в комментариях.

Код, котрый я запихивал в отладчик:

```
    using System;

    namespace DebMsil2 {
        class Program {

            struct Point {
                public int X, Y;
            }
            static void Main(string[] args) {
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key!");
                Console.ReadLine();
                
                Point p;
                p.X = 12;
                p.Y = 15;

                Console.WriteLine("x" + "y" + "z");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Картинка 1 (Windows debugger):
[image: Windows debugger]

Картинка 2 (ILDASM):
[image: ILDASM]

Картинка 3 (LINQPAD):
[image: LINQPAD]

Картинка 4 (назначаем в DILE startup point):
[image: назначаем в DILE startup point]

Картинка 5 (процесс отладки в DILE):
[image: процесс отладки в DILE]

Картинка 6 (просмотр значений полей объекта):
[image: просмотр значений полей объекта]

Картинка 7 (победитель - Решарпер, включаем показ IL кода):
[image: победитель - Решарпер, включаем показ IL кода]

Картинка 8 (победитель - Решарпер, вот как он показывает IL код):
[image: победитель - Решарпер, вот как он показывает IL код]

Comment: Взял LINQPad, пользуюсь им, удобно)

Comment: "я не нашел решения, которое бы работало прямо из VS" - resharper же

Comment: Удивительно, что я этого не знал! Исправляю ответ!